# prove a non-constant and T-periodic curve is closed?

Tags: differential-geometry

I don't really understand what this question is asking for...

First of all, 
A curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be **T-periodic** if $\gamma(t+T)=\gamma(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Second of all, if this curve is not constant and $T \neq 0$, then we say this curve is **closed**.

Where the curve $\gamma$ is assumed to be smooth.

However, this question asks:
**If $\gamma:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth non-constant curve that is T-periodic for some $T >0$,prove that this curve is closed.**

What?? Isn't this just a definition? Am i misunderstanding the definition here?

this is a problem in Chapter one of Andrew Pressley's *Elementary Differential Geometry*. This problem is given in the section where he stated the definition i given above, so i should use the given definition right? but if i used the given definition, then what is the meaning of asking this question?

Comment: I see what you mean. Maybe it means a different sense of the word closed? Where does the question come from?

Comment: @user326210 this question comes from Elementary Differential Geometry by Andrew Pressley. It is question 1.4.6 in chapter one.

Comment: A smooth closed curve can also be defined as $\phi: S^1\to\mathbb R^n$ where $\phi$ is smooth, but that would not fundamentally differ from your definition.

Comment: @zwim this is a problem in Chapter one of Andrew Pressley's Elementary Differential Geometry.  This problem is given in the section where he stated the definition i given above, so i should use the given definition right? but if i used the given definition, then what is the meaning of asking this question?

Comment: http://1clickurls.com/M7L-uhy I've just had a look at the book,in exercise 1.4.6 they do not assume smoothness (typo ?) but apart from that it is exactly def 1.4.1, so I agree that I do not see the point of the exercise either.

Comment: @zwim He said at the beginning of chapter that all curves in this book are assumed to be smooth, so.. it is actually smooth. Maybe this question is a mistake....